# Не удается подключиться к файловой БД 1С на Windows с Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, 1с, windows-7

Не удается подключиться к файловой БД 1С на Windows 7 с Ubuntu 20.04.
Версия 1С Предприятия: 8.3.15.1958

При попытке подключиться через **толстый клиент** выдает ошибку:

> Ошибка при выполнении операции с информационной базой
> Ошибка открытия файла базы данных '/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=accountant-pc,share=users/ГлавБух/Documents/Rarus/RetailShopOpticRelocated/1Cv8.1CD'
> по причине:
> Ошибка открытия файла базы данных '/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=accountant-pc,share=users/ГлавБух/Documents/Rarus/RetailShopOpticRelocated/1Cv8.1CD'

При попытке подключиться через **тонкий клиент** выдает ошибку:

> Невосстановимая ошибка
> Ошибка при выполнении запроса POST к ресурсу /e1cib/login:
> по причине:
> Ошибка при выполнении операции с информационной базой
> Ошибка открытия файла базы данных '/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=accountant-pc,share=users/ГлавБух/Documents/Rarus/RetailShopOpticRelocated/1Cv8.1CD'
> по причине:
> Ошибка открытия файла базы данных '/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=accountant-pc,share=users/ГлавБух/Documents/Rarus/RetailShopOpticRelocated/1Cv8.1CD'

Comment: А права на самбашару-то есть?

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понял. Доступ к директории с БД открыт для всех пользователей. В smb.conf рабочую группу переписал под группу компа с БД. Что-то нужно было сделать еще?

Comment: Хз, просто очень часто люди пришедшие с винды не врубаются в концепцию разделения доступа и спотыкаются прям на этом.